Finding the derivative of the eigenspace of a matrix dependent on a parameter x when the eigenvalue given has algebraic multiplicity 2
There exists a matrix A $\in {R} ^{3*3}$ which has a parameter a. When a = 0, then A has the generalized eigenspace that is spanned by $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ (denoting these 2 as the top 2 elements of a column vector of dimension 3) for an eigenvalue $\lambda_0$ with $AM(\lambda_0) = 2$.
When a is different from 0, then A has 2 eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ which are close to $\lambda_0$ both with AM = 1. The eigenspace of the eigenvectors for both $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ is given by: $f(a)x_1 + g(a)x_2 + x_3 = C$ where C is a constant. (f(0) = g(0) = 0).
Any ideas about how one might go about finding f'(0) and g'(0)?
